# How can I convert a float into int using the 'round' method in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, database

I tried with

`select ROUND(1235.53)
--(It can contain "n" digit of scale)`

But I got this error:

> The round function requires 2 to 3 arguments.

I am not sure what is the use of other parameters.

Comment: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175003(v=sql.110).aspx

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Better to use **CAST INT/CEILING/FLOOR**:

```
SELECT CEILING(1235.53)
SELECT FLOOR(1235.53)
SELECT CAST(1235.53 AS INT)
```

**CEILING**: Gives you the upper bound integer value

[image]

**FLOOR**: Gives you the lower bound integer value

[image]

Comment: The OP says "using round method", so this does not work as requested.

Comment: Thank you. Maybe I missed it. `SELECT CEILING(1235.53)` "gives you upper bound integer value". `SELECT FLOOR(1235.53)` "gives you lower bound integer value". `SELECT CAST(1235.53 AS INT)` does the same as FLOOR. I've repeated (and thus read) your whole answer. Nothing in it rounds off (e.g. `FUNCTION (1235.43)` should return 1235, and `FUNCTION (1235.53)` should return 1236)

Answer (score 41):

Set decimals to zero

```
select cast(ROUND(1235.53,0) as int)  Returns 1236

select cast(1235.53 as int)           Returns 1235
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but i wanted to avoid cast method. Is it possible without cast?

Comment: No, this requires a cast because `ROUND()` will return the same type as it was given.  E.g. - if the first parameter is a `float`, `ROUND()` will return a `float` value.  Why are you trying to avoid casting?

Comment: @ManishKumawat why do you want to avoid casting

Comment: @JesseWilliams No specific reason. I just wanted to avoid multiple functions. I got the answer, i can use floor and CEILING function. Thanks for the suggestions. I can't up vote you answer as i don't have required reputation. Sorry :(

Comment: @ManishKumawat No worries about the vote.  ceiling(2.01) returns 3, but it still is a FLOAT not an INT.  Your question was how to convert a float to an INT.

Comment: Correct @JohnCappelletti, but the value is a whole number so i don't need it to convert into int. My purpose was to get a whole number.

Comment: Note that this causes an error with integer overflow if the float is too big, of course.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews  Yes as would any number > 2.14B  If the target was an INT, I think it safe to assume they know their values are < 2.14B

Comment: If you don't have some bizarre restriction on avoiding multiple functions, `CAST(ROUND(<value>, 0) AS int)` is likely the version you want. This really is the superior answer.

Comment: You could easily write a user function that takes float and returns an int and hides the CAST

Comment: @sofend Yes, but you wouldn't gain anything, and would most likely lose performance.

Comment: @Kumawat if you don't like CAST use ROUND(1235.53,0) -1

Comment: @Kumawat  1) Your approach and selected answer still does not produce an INT.  2)  Your -1 assumes a round UP.   3) This answer is 6 years 14 days 22 hours 58 minutes 45 seconds old  I'm sure OP has moved on from now

Answer (score 1):

Here is another approach that just formats the result into the desired format:

```sql
SELECT FORMAT(ROUND(1235.53,0), 'N0')
```

'N' stands for numerical format and the digit behind it controls the number of decimal points.